# SQL Query - how do I order part of my data in alphabetical order, and part by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a small piece of data (15 records) where part of it I want ordered in alphabetical order, and part of it ordered by ID

Image 1 shows my data in the original order

[image]

After doing the query `SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY code;`

Image 2 shows my data now in alphabetical order, which is great however I would like the top 2 records to be ordered by id

[image]

Image 3 shows how I would like my data to look

[image]

Could someone help with my query please?

Comment: Are you, bye any chance, trying to order the rows in alphabetical order of the first second, and then ID?

Comment: Apologies I have now added the tag as suggested. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. And no `LUX-INT` and `LUX-CONT` do not need ordering by alphabetical order, just by ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assumed `id` is an integer. You can use conditional `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Note for the first expression `case when code in ('LUX-INT', 'LUX-CONT') then -id end desc`, it will return `id` or `NULL`. As `NULL` will comes first in `ORDER BY`, I use `DESC` and negate the `id` value so that `id` is in ascending order

```
order by case when code in ('LUX-INT', 'LUX-CONT') then -id end desc, code
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY case when code in ('LUX INT','LUX-CONT') then id else code end
```

Comment: unless `id` is a string data type else it will get conversion error

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
order by (case when code in ('LUX-INT', 'LUX-CONT') then 1 else 2 end),   -- put the special codes first
         (case when code in ('LUX-INT', 'LUX-CONT') then code end),       -- order them alphabetically
         id                                                               -- order the rest by id
```

This works regardless of the types and collations of the underlying columns.